# Applying second and third Normal Form

Tags: normalization, dependencies

> Let be a relation `R(NameFile, Size, Directory, DateCreation,HourCreation,Login,AutAccess,DateAccess,TypeAcces`
>
> ```
> F={NF,D→S;
>    NF, D →DC;
>    NF, D→HC;
>    L,NF,D→A;
>    L,NF,D,DA,HA→TA;
> }
> ```
>
> Part of the instances are given in the following array:
>
> [image: Example]
>
> **1. What are the minimal keys of R? Why?**
>
> **2. In which normal type is R? Why?**

I only know that:

- a key is minimal when every attributes that appears in no functional
  dependency is in every minimal keys
- Every attributes that appears only on the left of the FD is in every
  keys.
- Every attributes that appears only on the right of the DF isn't in
  any key.

Therefore we should have `K1={NF,R,L,DA,HA}` as the only minimal key.

What type of Normal Form is relation R?

I know that

1. something is **1NF** if forall attributes of R, there is an atomic
   value

Therefore, it is at least 1NF,

2. something is **2NF** iif:

   - The scheme is at least 1NF
   - Forall An attribute, not in any key, A doesn't depends to part of the key. that is to say not in any functional dependency.
3. A scheme of relation R is **3NF** iif

   - The scheme is 2NF
   - Not exists a transitive functional dependency

But I don't know what to do from there... I don't even understand the two last definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only candidate key of your relation is {D DA HA L NF} (perhaps with R you mean D?)

You can verify this by calculating the closure of those attributes, {D DA HA L NF}<sup>+</sup>, and seeing that it contains all the attributes, while, if you remove any one of them, the closure of the remaining set *does not* contains all the attributes (*this* is the definition of a candidate key).

The relation is only in first normal form, since the second normal form requires the absence of partial dependencies, that is of dependencies in which non-prime attributes (i.e. attributes not belonging to any key) depends only on part of a key. In this case only the last functional dependency is not partial.